# Create function for `openai` and `ChatCompletion` in Python

Tags: python, openai-api

I am trying to create a simple function that will take a message (string) and pass it through to `openai.ChatCompletion.create()`, but when I use an F-string, it returns an object error. Not super familiar with debugging Python, so I am a bit stuck here.

```
def get_response(message):
    
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model = 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        temperature = 1,
        messages = [
            f"{{'role': 'user', 'content': '{message}'}}"
        ]
    )
    return response.choices[0]["message"]["content"]

# get_response('What is 2 + 2?')
```

It returns:

```
InvalidRequestError: "{'role': 'user', 'content': 'What is 2 + 2?'}" is not of type 'object' - 'messages.0'
```

I guess that I might need to cast the string to some unique class that `openai` has created, but I'm not quite sure how. Looked through the source code but couldn't find a reference to this class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Messages are actual object literals; you can't replace the object literals with a string version. But you can replace the strings *within* the object literal with an f-string:

```py
{"role": "user", "content": f"{message}"}
```

Or obviously in this example, an f-string is unnecessary so you can just put the name `message` right there:

```py
{"role": "user", "content": message}
```

Again, to emphasize, it is not equivalent to send a string that has the same syntax as the object literal format, instead of sending an actual object literal.

Comment: I think your outermost brackets are incorrect here. I may be wrong if there's some python syntax I'm unaware of https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat/introduction

Comment: @VioletRosenzweig you're absolutely right. fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Your messages need to be objects, not strings (see [here](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat/introduction))

```py
def get_response(message):
    
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model = 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        temperature = 1,
        messages = [
            {"role": "user", "content": message}
        ]
    )
    return response.choices[0]["message"]["content"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_response(message):
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model = 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        temperature = 1,
        messages  = [
        { 'role':'system','content' : 'You are a helpful ......'},
        { 'role':'user','content' : message},


    )
    return response.choices[0]["message"]["content"]  -> you can directly add the message variable as the users content property.
```